# Get a part of string with python

Tags: python

I am working with strings in python. I have a string like this one:

```
'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/xxiajdiojadf.jpg||2013-11-17,16:19:52||more text in this string'
```

To get the first and the second part of the string is easy, but what I need to do for the second part?, I mean I want to get the text after the second || . For the first ones:

```
url=s.split("||")[0] and  date=s.split("||")[1]
```

I have try with  `url=s.split("||")[2]` but I have nothing
Thanks in advance

Comment: weird, it work in my Python 3.6.9
>>> s = 'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/xxiajdiojadf.jpg||2013-11-17,16:19:52||more text in this string'
>>> s
'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/xxiajdiojadf.jpg||2013-11-17,16:19:52||more text in this string'
>>> s_list = s.split('||')
>>> s_list
['http://pbs.twimg.com/media/xxiajdiojadf.jpg', '2013-11-17,16:19:52', 'more text in this string']
>>> s_list[0]
'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/xxiajdiojadf.jpg'
>>> s_list[1]
'2013-11-17,16:19:52'
>>> s_list[2]
'more text in this string'

Comment: what you tried should work

Comment: @zoit can you please enter the error and python version as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have just made a typo. You logic is correct. On your third line you should use another variable, not 'url'.

A bit more terse way to do it would be:

```
url, date, descr = s.split("||")
```

https://repl.it/repls/WrongTinyCylinder#main.py

Answer (score 1):

You can get that using 2nd index:

```
s.split("||")[2]
```

output:

```
'more text in this string'
```

split will return the list.

```
>>> s.split("||")
['http://pbs.twimg.com/media/xxiajdiojadf.jpg', '2013-11-17,16:19:52', 'more text in this string']
>>> url,date,extra = s.split("||")
>>> print(url)
'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/xxiajdiojadf.jpg'
>>> print(date)
'2013-11-17,16:19:52'
>>> print(extra)
'more text in this string'
```